# initState calling function twice

Tags: flutter, function, api, init, dio

I'm trying to call Api function in initState of home page of bottom navigation bar, but when I install app and login and go to home page api function inside initState it get call twice.

here is my code,

```
GetRecordApiCall(context) async {
  // Call your API here and pass `_verificationCode` as a parameter
  final api = ApiServices(Dio(), "/getRecord");
  // Api response will get here
  final response = await api.ApiUser(toJson(), context);
  //Print response here
  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response}');
  print(
      'Response headers: ${response.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader]}');
  // New token will be saved here
  String decodeResponse = response.toString();
  Map<String, dynamic> res = jsonDecode(decodeResponse);
  res['token'] = '${response.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader]}';
  late var token = res['token'];
  token = token.substring(1, token.length - 1);
  print(token);
  // Shared preferences used here so we can store token which will get from api.
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sharedPreferences.setString('token', token);

  print("Get Record request send to api");

}


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GetRecordApiCall(context);
  }
```

Comment: can you share code how you redirecting to login page

Comment: I'm redirecting from login page to home page.

Comment: yes from login to home page share routing info

Comment: isPinState == 0 || isPinState == null && isPin == true
          ? Navigator.pushReplacement(context, CustomPageRoute(child: SetPin()))
          : Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, CustomPageRoute(child: HomePage()));

Comment: When you go from login to home page your init gets called, but is there any code in your bottom navigation that is calling home page again?

Comment: Yes, maybe it is because selectedIndex is zero.

Comment: that might be the case try changing the index and manually going to home page if same error comes

Comment: I have to show 0 index as home page, is there any way to call just initState while navigating

Comment: yes, if you can change your base page from home page to some empty page where you have bottom navigation placed then you can call that empty page and the selected index will be by default zero so your home page will get called only once

Comment: you just need one host page where you will call all child pages of the bottom navigation tab